flask application running on docker container cannot access Chromadb running on a seperate docker container
enter image description here
Hello So I have two docker containers running as shown in the image... One is a Chromadb for vector search and the other one is a flask backend for RAG chatbot.
Here is a basic flask code that shows what im trying to achieve
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from dotenv import main
import os
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
import chromadb


main.load_dotenv()


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods = ["GET"])
def home():
    client = chromadb.HttpClient(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
    db = Chroma(client=client, embedding_function=OpenAIEmbeddings())    
    response = db.similarity_search_with_score('hi', k=7)
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, port=9000)


I am just did
docker Pull
docker run -p 8000:8000 chromadb/chroma

To run the database on docker..
and here is my dockerfile for the flask app(really basic, it doesnt have much)
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 9000
CMD python3 ./plugin.py

I have them running on same network as well here is my network config
[
    {
        "Name": "my_network",
        "Id": "fc8486b7452682430b0c15ae3385db8d4e952b336849608c6a48068c0d802068",
        "Created": "2024-07-16T17:07:35.414480912Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "37598d7550732cbe1e6f6e5ed206d1cf8b74cf4c341bbae636799c83faf4fc2d": {
                "Name": "database",
                "EndpointID": "aba16a90d2955e242572cdbc4baf3e477c369e670f3a40880bf3b8a92d01deb5",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "89272e2ee9ea8fab90f6e5b433c85c3b33e1307807e73c8f9beea2c92f2d6177": {
                "Name": "chat",
                "EndpointID": "cea08658d1b2975c9e53618cc167563c1cf853a869d13cd89d970a9a7550dcf9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]

When I try to use the flask backend hosted on the docker container, it gives me the following error and I am not sure what the issue is. Any possible solutions?
2024-07-16 15:15:17 192.168.65.1 - - [16/Jul/2024 19:15:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2024-07-16 15:15:17 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 69, in map_httpcore_exceptions
2024-07-16 15:15:17     yield
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 233, in handle_request
2024-07-16 15:15:17     resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 216, in handle_request
2024-07-16 15:15:17     raise exc from None
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 196, in handle_request
2024-07-16 15:15:17     response = connection.handle_request(
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 99, in handle_request
2024-07-16 15:15:17     raise exc
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 76, in handle_request
2024-07-16 15:15:17     stream = self._connect(request)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 122, in _connect
2024-07-16 15:15:17     stream = self._network_backend.connect_tcp(**kwargs)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/sync.py", line 213, in connect_tcp
2024-07-16 15:15:17     sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
2024-07-16 15:15:17     self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 14, in map_exceptions
2024-07-16 15:15:17     raise to_exc(exc) from exc
2024-07-16 15:15:17 httpcore.ConnectError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2024-07-16 15:15:17 
2024-07-16 15:15:17 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2024-07-16 15:15:17 
2024-07-16 15:15:17 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 371, in _validate_tenant_database
2024-07-16 15:15:17     self._admin_client.get_tenant(name=tenant)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 419, in get_tenant
2024-07-16 15:15:17     return self._server.get_tenant(name=name)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/telemetry/opentelemetry/__init__.py", line 146, in wrapper
2024-07-16 15:15:17     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/api/fastapi.py", line 137, in get_tenant
2024-07-16 15:15:17     resp_json = self._make_request("get", "/tenants/" + name)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/api/fastapi.py", line 86, in _make_request
2024-07-16 15:15:17     response = self._session.request(method, url, **cast(Any, kwargs))
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 827, in request
2024-07-16 15:15:17     return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 914, in send
2024-07-16 15:15:17     response = self._send_handling_auth(
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 942, in _send_handling_auth
2024-07-16 15:15:17     response = self._send_handling_redirects(
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 979, in _send_handling_redirects
2024-07-16 15:15:17     response = self._send_single_request(request)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1015, in _send_single_request
2024-07-16 15:15:17     response = transport.handle_request(request)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 233, in handle_request
2024-07-16 15:15:17     resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
2024-07-16 15:15:17     self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 86, in map_httpcore_exceptions
2024-07-16 15:15:17     raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
2024-07-16 15:15:17 httpx.ConnectError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2024-07-16 15:15:17 
2024-07-16 15:15:17 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2024-07-16 15:15:17 
2024-07-16 15:15:17 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1498, in __call__
2024-07-16 15:15:17     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1476, in wsgi_app
2024-07-16 15:15:17     response = self.handle_exception(e)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
2024-07-16 15:15:17     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
2024-07-16 15:15:17     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
2024-07-16 15:15:17     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
2024-07-16 15:15:17     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/app/plugin.py", line 33, in home
2024-07-16 15:15:17     response = chat(["hi"])
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/app/Chat.py", line 24, in chat
2024-07-16 15:15:17     response = query_rag(msgs)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/app/Query.py", line 45, in query_rag
2024-07-16 15:15:17     client = chromadb.HttpClient(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/__init__.py", line 204, in HttpClient
2024-07-16 15:15:17     return ClientCreator(tenant=tenant, database=database, settings=settings)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 61, in __init__
2024-07-16 15:15:17     self._validate_tenant_database(tenant=tenant, database=database)
2024-07-16 15:15:17   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 373, in _validate_tenant_database
2024-07-16 15:15:17     raise ValueError(
2024-07-16 15:15:17 ValueError: Could not connect to a Chroma server. Are you sure it is running?


Can you show us the actual flask code?

Hey I just put a very short version that shows what im trying to do

You'll need to put the chromadb container on the same network as the flask container

Hey I added in my network config, Could you take a look?

0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address that means "all interfaces".  That makes sense in a "listen" or "bind" argument, but it seems like you're using it in an outbound HttpClient object.  Do you need to use a different name here; maybe like How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname"?  How are you starting the containers and attaching them to the same network?  (The complete docker run commands will be more interesting than the docker network inspect output.)

It's unclear how you're running chromadb/chroma but if you're doing something of the form docker run --interactive --tty --rm --network=my_network --name=foo --publish=8000:8000 chromadb/chroma then, your Python code (if running on the same network) would address the database as chromadb.HttpClient(host='foo', port=8000).
